# SQL help on group by query with inline query

Tags: sql, oracle

I've these 2 tables. I want to count number of con_id which has remark '1' continuously for the last period(s).
ex: 2 for A1, 1 for A3, but 0 for A2 and B1 as they don't have '1' continuously for the latest result(s) for the following table.

t_conmast

- con_id [pk]
- off_code

```
  
con_id off_code
A1     1
A2     1
B1     2
A3     1
```

t_readbak

- con_id [fk]
- counter
- remark
- timestamp [not shown in the table; auto inserted by system]

```
con_id counter remark timestamp
A1     1      0
A1     3      1
A1     6      1
B1     1      1
B1     2      0
A2     1      0
A2     2      1
A2     3      0
A3     1      1
```

*what I tried and failed* (I added the off_code just to get result for a single office)

```
select con_id, 
       count(con_id) 
from t_readbak 
where remark=1 and timestamp > (select max(timestamp) 
                                from t_readbak 
                                where remark=0 
                                group by con_id) 
and con_id in (select con_id from t_conmast where off_code=1)
```

Expected output

```
con_id count(con_id)
A1     2
A2     0 
A3     1
B1     0
```

Comment: Can you post the expected output based on the data in your question?

Comment: Can you (a) describe how you define a "period" (as in *"I want to count number of con_id which has remark '1' continuously for the last period(s)"*), (b) clarify the significance of office (presumably defined by `off_code`) and (c) add timestamp data to your sample dataset?

Comment: 1>By period I want to mean entries. 2>Data are stored in a single database for multiple offices. A office can have many consumers. I want records to be filtered by offices. 3>Timestamp is current system date at the time of entry in DD-MMM-YYYY format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach that I took to solving this.  First, calculate a cumulative sum of remark going backwards for each `con_id`.  Then, the first time that you hit a row where `remark = 0`, use the value on that row.  You can find the first such row using `row_number()`.

The complication is when you have no remarks with a value of 0.  In that case, you just take the total number.

The following query combines this logic into SQL:

```
select rb.con_id,
       (case when NumZeros = 0 then numRemarks else cumsum end) as count1
from (select rb.*,
             SUM(remark) over (partition by con_id order by counter desc) as cumsum,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by con_id, remark order by counter desc) as remark_counter,
             SUM(case when remark = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NumZeros,
             SUM(remark) over (partition by con_id) as numRemarks
      from t_readbak rb
     ) rb
where (remark_counter = 1 and remark = 0) or
      (NumZeros = 0 and remark_counter = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A left self join might work.  Something like this:

```
select con_id, count(*) records
from t_readback t1 left join t_readback t2 using (con_id, remark)
where remark = 1
and t1.counter < t2.counter
group by con_id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you only want to include `con_id` counts if *every* `remark` in the period is `1`, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
  con_id,
  COUNT(CASE remark = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Remark1Count,
  COUNT(CASE remark <> 1 THEN 1 END) AS RemarkNot1Count
FROM t_conmast
INNER JOIN t_readbak ON t_conmast.con_id = t_readbak.con_id
WHERE your-timestamp-condition
GROUP BY con_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE remark <> 1 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

The `HAVING` will filter out any `con_id` that has a `remark <> 1`.

Answer (score 1):

get the maximum timestamp for each `con_id` where `remark` is 0.
thereafter, again for each `con_id`, count items with younger timestamps. `remark` is set to 1 in these records by construction:

```
    select con_id
         , count(*)
      from t_readbak master
inner join t_conmast office on (     office.off_code = 1
                                 and office.con_id   = master.con_id )
inner join (
                select con_id           con_id
                     , max(timestamp)   ts
                  from (
                            select con_id
                                 , remark
                                 , timestamp
                              from t_readbak
                             where remark = 0
                       ) noremark
              group by con_id
            ) cutoff
         on ( master.con_id = cutoff.con_id )
      where master.timestamp > cutoff.ts
   group by master.con_id
          ;
```

replace `timestamp` ( `max(timestamp)` ) by `counter` ( `min(counter)`) and change the comparison operator if you can't trust your timestamp ordering.